# GROUP_CONCAT with a self exclusion

Tags: mysql

Perhaps I'm missing some logic or a way to easily do this.

Have a table with colors, some may have 0, 1, 2, 3 or more matching other colors within the same `colorHue`

```
id  colorName   colorHue    ColorNumber
----------------------------------------------------
1   Orange      Og          1000
2   Pumpkin     Og          1000
3   Red         Rd          1001
4   Brick       Rd          1001
5   Carrot      Og          1000
6   Blue        Blue        1002
7   Scarlet     Rd          1001
```

I need a `VIEW` with all of the colors listed and the other possible ones without showing the color name of the current row.

```
id  colorName   Other Colors
----------------------------------------------------
1   Orange      Pumpkin,Carrot
2   Pumpkin     Orange,Carrot
3   Red         Brick,Scarlet
4   Brick       Red,Scarlet
5   Carrot      Orange,Pumpkin
6   Blue        
7   Scarlet     Red,Brick
```

I can easily get a `GROUP_CONCAT` of all of them but can't figure out how to eliminate the self reference to the current row. So I get this:

```
id  colorName   Other Colors
----------------------------------------------------
1   Orange      Orange,Pumpkin,Carrot
2   Pumpkin     Orange,Pumpkin,Carrot
3   Red         Red,Brick,Scarlet
4   Brick       Red,Brick,Scarlet
5   Carrot      Orange,Pumpkin,Carrot
6   Blue        Blue
7   Scarlet     Red,Brick,Scarlet
```

Comment: so what condition is to exclude `Orange` from the list in first row?

Comment: oh! Isee, I think I've got your goal

Answer (score 3):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43c122/2

```
SELECT colorHue, 
      GROUP_CONCAT(IF(colorHue=colorName,null,colorName))
FROM colors
GROUP BY colorHue
```

**UPDATE** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43c122/8

```
SELECT c.*, 
      GROUP_CONCAT(c1.colorName)
FROM colors c
LEFT JOIN colors c1
ON c.colorHue = c1.colorHue
   AND c.id != c1.id
GROUP BY c.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but that doesn't output the list. Also, what if the colorHue was not the name of a color but an abbreviation? Org, Rd, B, Gr, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by *but that doesn't output the list*? did you visit the fiddle?

Comment: Yes I did. I guess simple explanation of what I need was too simple. Change colorHue values to O for Orange, R for Red and B for Blue and see what happens. I need the output I showed as table 2 above. Each Color, with the alternatives, but not the actual color.

Comment: that is exctly what my query does. provide your fiddle with your data to discuss or to explain your problem

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/033e5d/4  As I said, I should not have made it so simple. The colorHue isn't a color but a code.

Comment: I still don't understand. what is your last comment point is? Can you tell me according to the data you've posted in OP how many records should return the correct query? 7 ?

Comment: Perfect, so you have to do a self join back on the GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: @Tom **I have to do** nothing. I did ask you a question to get some info that I can use to help you. If you don't need any help I definitely **have to do nothing**

Comment: All of them, just like your 2nd sqlfiddle. That is exactly what I need, I was just trying to understand how the query worked. A join back on the query? Do know of a documentation link on how to join back on the 1st results? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @tom I would say it is not `JOIN` back *to result*, that is `JOIN` to the *table*. just in this case it is the same table. But join syntax is absolutely the same https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html